# Did Dumbledore and McGonagall cheat so the Gryffindors would win the House and Quidditch Cups?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, albus-dumbledore, quidditch

When Harry is a first year, Professor McGonagall recommends Harry as seeker and  gifts him a [Nimbus 2000](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/nimbus-racing-broom-company/nimbus-2000/), breaking the house rule according to which first years are not allowed to have brooms. 
The idea is probably that flying (and especially Quidditch) is too dangerous, and first years shouldn't dodge Bludgers or fly unsupervised. It's allowed to fly under the supervision of Madame Hooch, on school brooms. Harry was good, but my impression was that he wasn't as good as Quidditch prodigy Viktor Krum, to justify making him the youngest seeker in 100 years.

When Harry enters Hogwarts, Slytherin house is on a winning streak for both the House and the Quidditch Cup. The Seeker is extremely important to the outcome of the game, so could it be that Minerva was desperate enough to change tactics and use a young, lightweight seeker, giving an unfair advantage to the Gryffindor team?

Later, in Harry's third year Professor McGonagall says to Harry:

> "...Potter- do try and win, won't you? Or we'll be out of the running
>   for the eighth year in a row, as Professor Snape was kind enough to
>   remind me only last night…" <sub>~Harry Potter and the Prisoner of
>   Azkaban - Chapter 12: The Patronus</sub>

In sixth year Harry uses a spell of unknown origin that almost kills another student, refusing to tell the source that spell come from and if there's more such things he learned. Yet McGanagall has no intention to suspend Harry from the team.

Same with the House Cup. In first year Dumbledore awards exactly enough points so Gryffindor would win. How that's fair? It's not as if other houses were given the chance to fight Voldemort or had the cloak of invisibility.

There is a conversation in Philosopher's Stone when the trio discusses Dumbledore:

> "D'you think he meant you to do it?" said Ron. "Sending you your
>   father's cloak and everything?" "Well, " Hermione exploded, "if he did
>   -- I mean to say that's terrible
>   -- you could have been killed." "No, it isn't," said Harry thoughtfully. "He's a funny man, Dumbledore. I think he sort of wanted
>   to give me a chance. I think he knows more or less everything that
>   goes on here, you know. I reckon he had a pretty good idea we were
>   going to try, and instead of stopping us, he just taught us enough to
>   help. I don't think it was an accident he let me find out how the
>   mirror worked. It's almost like he thought I had the right to face
>   Voldemort if I could...." "Yeah, Dumbledore's off his rocker, all
>   right," said Ron proudly. <sub>~Harry Potter and the Philosopher's
>   Stone - Chapter 17: The Man with Two Faces</sub>

So if Dumbledore was leading Harry and did everything to ensure he'd fight Voldemort and that he would be ready, how it is fair to award points for it?

Between Snape openly favouring the Slytherins and Dumbledore and McGonagall bending the rules and cheating do other houses even stand a chance to win?

Comment: Don't forget in Book 6 when Snape is going to deduct a small number of points from Gryffindor which will give them negative points, and McGonngal awards something like 200pts on the spot so Snape can have something to deduct from :)

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. "Yes" :) Bloody Gryffindor tossers.

Comment: Was Harry as good as Viktor Krum? Probably not, but there was never a direct comparison, so who can say? He *could* have been the best Seeker (or player) Hogwarts had seen in a while nonetheless, though, since Krum attended Durmstrang.

Comment: @Himarm not quite fair on the most horrible toad of them all, she banned one of the weasleys for being held back (because he would have attacked if he could have), but Harry definitely attacked Malfoy, hitting him with the hand still holding the Snitch, because he insulted his dead mother (which is pretty reasonable, I'm not saying it's not!)

Comment: Even if some teachers showed favoritism, you must understand that using a light weight seeker is a game tactic. not cheating.

Comment: Can McGonagall really said to be unfair when she awarded Harry and Ron a mere 10 points for **defeating a fully-grown mountain troll** in their first year?

Comment: @NKCampbell You mean book five. How could what you say be possible in year six? Severus and the other Death Eaters weren't there were they? And you left out the fact that she also gave Luna points. And it was 50 each so the Gryffindors were actually given 250 total.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### They at least show favoritism

**They did indeed show favoritism, but not all the examples you mention are cheating.**

As you mentioned, Dumbledore awarded Gryffindor just enough points to push them ahead of Slytherin:

> The din was deafening. Those who could add up while yelling themselves
>   hoarse knew that Gryffindor now had four hundred and seventy-two
>   points—exactly the same as Slytherin. They had tied for the house cup -- if only Dumbledore had given Harry just one more point .
>
> Dumbledore
>   raised his hand. The room gradually fell silent. "There are all kinds
>   of courage," said Dumbledore, smiling.
>
> "It takes a great deal of
>   bravery to stand up to our enemies, but just as much to stand up to
>   our friends. I therefore award ten points to Mr. Neville Longbottom."
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*

Ten points is really a rather small reward. While one could make a good argument for awarding lots of points based on saving the world, it seems clear that the precise number of points was calculated to put Gryffindor in first place.

McGonagall also is highly biased against Slytherin, and particularly does not want to see Snape win any accolades, as evidenced in the first quote in the question.

Her attitude when awarding points at the end of *Order of the Phoenix* makes this quite plain.

> “So that’s fifty each for Potter, the two Weasleys, Longbottom, and
>   Miss Granger,” said Professor McGonagall, and a shower of rubies fell
>   down into the bottom bulb of Gryffindor’s hourglass as she spoke. “Oh
>   — and fifty for Miss Lovegood, **I suppose**,” she added, and a number of
>   sapphires fell into Ravenclaw’s glass.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

Notice how Luna, a Ravenclaw, is merely an afterthought.

**It *is* worth noting that in all cases in which points were awarded, McGonagall and Dumbledore had *very* good reason to award points.** It is also true, however, that they specifically seized upon these ambiguous instances to put Gryffindor ahead of Slytherin.

---

That said, there is at least one thing mentioned in the question that was not favoritism or cheating.

- **Not suspending Harry from Quidditch after his use of *Sectumsempra*.**

  This was self-defense, to start with. Malfoy had been about to use the Cruciatus Curse on Harry:

  > There was a loud bang and the bin behind Harry exploded; Harry
  >   attempted a Leg-Locker Curse that backfired off the wall behind
  >   Malfoy's
  >   ear and smashed the cistern beneath Moaning Myrtle, who screamed
  >   loudly;
  >   water poured everywhere and Harry slipped as Malfoy, his face
  >   contorted,
  >   cried, "*Cruci* —"
  >
  > "*SECTUMSEMPRA*!" bellowed Harry from the floor, waving his wand
  >   wildly.
  >
  > —*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*

  Second, Harry had no idea what the spell did, beside that it was offensive, and so was guilty of recklessness in a possibly lethal situation at worst.

  And while McGonagall did not suspend Harry in that case, Snape *did*.

Comment: Harry was suspended from the quidditch 6th year by snape. Ginny wins it flying as seaker and harry and her make out.  OP is confusing Harry getting suspended by umbridge in year 5. while he got suspended for sectumsempra in year 6.

Comment: @Himarm - I know. I'm explaining why *McGonagall* did not suspend Harry.

Comment: she really didnt have a chance too since snape already had, though technically hes not suspended from the team, hes just in detention during the match

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can have multiples of five in the awarding and deduction of points, in fact, off the top of my head, after the incident with the troll in *PS* Hermione is docked 5 and the boys are awarded 5. This is a minor nitpick, though

Comment: @Au101 - Good point. I suspect Rowling forgot, though. After all, JKR is apparently not too good with maths.

Comment: @Adamant I've upvoted your answer and I don't have a problem with it, but I think that's a little unfair, that's not the only time five points are given out in the books, for example, Lupin gives out five points to everyone to tackle the Boggart in *PoA*, I wouldn't ... yeah, I just wouldn't double down on the multiples of ten point myself, I'm not really sure about that. *However* who gives out 45 points? or 55 points? You give out round numbers, don't you? You don't give 15, you give 10 or 20, but you might give out 5 for something more trivial.

Comment: I'm near certain you don't have any that aren't multiples of five :)

Comment: @Au101 - It's not unfair, it's just true. As JKR says [here](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2004/0304-wbd.htm), "Oh dear, maths." Her lack of maths skills has been noted by her and many others, particularly with respect to dates and ages in the series. See: Montague.

Comment: @Adamant without turning this comment thread into an extended conversation, I completely agree JKR sucks at maths, that's lore at this stage, but I think it's unfair to deduce that she just forgot 5 points could be awarded and that was how she justified Dumbledore's "favouritism" (I actually think everyone involved richly deserved their points, and at the end of the day, he was only undoing the damage done for getting Norbert out). She gives out 5 points more than once in the books, I just, I'm not at all convinced it was *that*. but otherwise, as I say, you have 10 points from me ;)

Comment: In the *Sectumsempra* case I think that was more about not wanting to expel Harry because of his special role in the fight against Voldemort.

Comment: I'd also like to note that Malfoy was half a syllable away from *casting an Unforgivable Curse* and there's no way to claim he was doing anything else. To put in perspective, Harry is guilty of shooting a fellow soldier; but he did so because said soldier was in the process of committing a war crime.

Comment: @Shadur - I'm not sure Harry had time to think about anything other than that Malfoy was casting a spell, to be honest. If he'd waited to hear what spell Malfoy was casting, he wouldn't have had an opportunity to respond.

Comment: @Shadur Yes.. because using a spell one doesn't know what it does and simply marked 'For Enemies' isn't (to use your wording) 'a war crime'? What a joke that is. And even if you want to go there it's not like (a) Harry hadn't tried the year before; (b) he tried it again on Severus later that year; (c) he successfully cast it on Carrow in year seven; and (d) he also cast Imperio several times in year seven.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That's how I always looked at it with the trio. They were critical to defeating Voldemort and if they weren't given the training, the experience, the world would have been lost.

Answer (score 24):

### Not really.

Firstly, a nitpick. Gryffindor *didn't* win the Quidditch Cup that year. It's not entirely clear but from the following quotes I'd infer that Slytherin won it alongside the House Cup (before Dumbledore awarded Gryffindor the extra points, that is).

> "The points are all in and Slytherin won, of course - you missed the last Quidditch match, we were steamrollered by Ravenclaw without you - but the food'll be good."
>   <sub>*(Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 17, The Man With Two Faces)*</sub>
>
> "Gryffindor haven't won for seven years now. OK, so we've had the worst luck in the world - injuries - then the tournament being called off last year..."
>   <sub>*(Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 8, Flight of the Fat Lady)*</sub>

Now it seems that Quidditch scores contribute to the totals for the House Cup. Harry expresses dismay that the points he loses for being out of bed wipe out those he won for Quidditch. So having a good Quidditch team certainly helps with regards to winning the House Cup. But, when it comes to the Quidditch scoring system itself, remember that this is basically a sport which is invented **in such a way as to make Harry a hero**. Even the best of Chasers is unlikely to win their team more than 50 or 60 points in a game. The Seeker gets 150 points and almost always wins the match just by pulling off their signature move. So, in that sense, the entire House Cup wasn't fair to begin with because it gives a disproportionate reward to Quidditch Seekers over and above everyone else. This was true of all the houses.

McGonagall isn't in my view guilty of showing favouritism in allowing Harry onto the team. He is uncommonly good, the sort of Quidditch player that Hogwarts hadn't seen for many generations.

> "Are you serious, Professor?"
>   "Absolutely," said Professor McGonagall crisply. "The boy's a natural. I've never seen anything like it...He caught that thing in his hand after a fifty-foot dive...Didn't even scratch himself. Charlie Weasley couldn't have done it."
>   <sub>*(Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 9, The Midnight Duel)*</sub>

True, she does bend the rule about first years not having brooms. But that rule is surely there to ensure the safety of first-years and make sure that they don't cause a danger to themselves or others until they have completed their Flying Lessons. Harry has obviously just demonstrated that he is not only able to fly competently but that he's one of the most talented flyers that Hogwarts has ever seen. There's no reason to prevent him joining the Gryffindor team. As is the case with Muggle sports, if you're good enough then you're old enough.

Where McGonagall arguably *is* culpable is in buying Harry a top-of-the-range Nimbus 2000. This was not strictly necessary. However, in a competition where a player's father can buy the *entire team* top broomsticks (as Lucius Malfoy does a year later), I'd argue that it's not really a big deal. Professor Flitwick was the Head of another house and he didn't make any objections.

> "Potter's been sent a broomstick, Professor," said Malfoy quickly.
>   "Yes, yes, that's right," said Professor Flitwick, **beaming at Harry**. "Professor McGonagall told me all about the special circumstances, Potter. And what model is it?"
>   <sub>*(Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 10, Hallowe'en)*</sub>

---

### As for the House Cup, the entire scoring system is all over the place.

Yes, Heads of Houses are biased as hell. McGonagall is nowhere near as bad as Snape in this regard, when you consider how he docked points for this sort of thing:

> "Five more points from Gryffindor for being an insufferable know-it-all."
>   <sub>*(Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 9, Grim Defeat)*</sub>

Indeed, if Snape takes points away from Gryffindor for no reason, McGonagall if anything seems curiously unwilling to reward her own House. Consider how she gives out a mere ten points to Ron and Harry - two **first years** who **defeat a fully-grown mountain troll** without any help from teachers or other students, saving Hermione's life in the process.

> "Well, I still say you were lucky, but not many first-years could have taken on a fully-grown mountain troll. You each win Gryffindor five points."
>   <sub>*(Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 10, Hallowe'en)*</sub>

This is surely a very measly reward for such a huge achievement! My conclusion would be that inter-House bias certainly does play a role in the rewarding and docking of points. Therefore, what happened at the end of *The Philosopher's Stone* doesn't seem to be too far out of the ordinary.

It is unfair, true. It hardly seems just for the diligent Slytherin students who'd been receiving five or ten points for their efforts on homework during the entire school year. Their efforts are overridden entirely by the points Harry, Ron, Hermione and Neville get right at the end of the year. Dumbledore obviously awarded the points in such a way that Gryffindor would very narrowly win. This is hardly fair.

Yet we shouldn't underestimate the trio's achievement either. They thwart the return of Lord Voldemort into eternal life. This is something that any grown-up wizard would be immensely proud of. Dumbledore is hardly overreacting by giving them the House Cup. If anything, they deserve a lot more. I wouldn't say Dumbledore cheated. I'd say he manipulated the system to justly reward the extraordinary (historic, really) efforts of some young Gryffindors by giving them something he knew they'd appreciate - recognition by the rest of the school and the end-of-year prize. As Headmaster, he was well within his rights to give them this.

Comment: I think McGonagall probably gave them very few points for taking on the troll because they disobeyed orders to go back to their dorms, and at the end of the day they *could* have been killed, and they almost were. Other than that good answer, I wasn't aware quidditch points contributed to the overall house points.

Comment: @Mike.C.Ford, I think McGonagall gave them so few points because inflation.  ;)  No, really.  All the points values (deductions and awards) seem to get bigger as the series progresses.  Rowling finding her feet, I'd say.  I only recall one time *ever* that points are deducted singly (rather than in increments of five): Harry's first Potions lesson.

Comment: @Wildcard. I agree. The rewards and punishments seem to go up as you get older and go through the years.

Comment: +1 for  *...in such a way as to make Harry a hero*. I'm glad I'm not the only one who thinks Quditich has some pretty stupid rules, all of which exist to make Harry look cool

Comment: The real question is why anyone cares about the points after the first year or two when the realize how arbitrary they are. It's like they're on *Whose Line* or something. "Welcome to Hogwarts, the school where everything's made up and the points don't matter."

Answer (score 2):

As a bit of a bonus to what the other answers contain, remember that at this point of the tale, it is necessary to establish that there no friendship between Snape and the rest of the Hogwarts staff, and especially between Dumbledore and Snape. There is a campaign of misdirection going on against He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named, and this includes misdirecting those who are loyal to him.

Granted, Snape probably would not have gotten on with McGonagall, and his relationship with Dumbledore would never have been close, but to keep up the charade they also work to ensure that during time when this ruse needs most earnestly to be effective, they are throwing little digs at Snape's prestige and dignity. All of the Death Eaters who are still loose (Lucius Malfoy *et al.*) see and hear of this and this helps Snape gain their trust (in most cases; Bellatrix was an exception).

Later this pays off. When Voldemort uses his Legilimency to dip into Snape's head, he sees Snape's hatred for Harry (which is mostly genuine), as well as memories of the slights against him by those to whom Harry is close. Seeing only dislike for his own enemies, Voldemort digs no deeper and never learns that he is being fooled by the biggest Occlumens ever.